# Preconditioning a least-squares problem?

Tags: least-squares, preconditioning

I need to solve an equation system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A \\
I
\end{pmatrix}
x
=
\begin{pmatrix}
b_0\\b_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
in the least-squares sense. Let's assume $I$ is the $n$-by-$n$ identity matrix, $A$ is some $m$-by-$n$ matrix, e.g., Laplace with Poisson boundary conditions.

I know a good preconditioner $M$ for $A$, so solving
$$
M^{-1} A x = M^{-1} b
$$
is easy. Can I make use of this when solving the least-squares problem?

Comment: Of course, your new preconditioner is $$P = \begin{bmatrix} M & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}$$ and you solve the preconditioned system $$P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} A\\ I \end{bmatrix} x = P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} b_0 \\ b_1\end{bmatrix}$$. Depending on the language/software package you use, implementation may be different; but in MATLAB, preconditioning LSQR (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lsqr.html) is no different from preconditioning GMRES.

Comment: I could be wrong but this looks to me that this is not the correct representation. Isn't $x=b_1$ a constraint that needs to be satisfied together with the equation $A x = b_0$?

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas, if the objective is to solve the equation in the least-squares sense, then isn't the final equation $\left[ A^T A + I \right] x = A^T b_0 + b_1$? If so, I am not sure if one can still use M as the preconditioner.

Comment: @ChennaK, firstly, that system is rarely explicitly formed in practice since SpMM is expensive. Secondly, it depends. It will do the job in the sense that one can solve the preconditioned linear system faster than the original system. But as Federico Poloni pointed out, you may not obtain the "unique" solution (assuming [A;I] is full-column rank) to the original system, but another solution. If the target is to solve the linear system then this should work. If it is to find the least squares solution, it may not.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas How is the solution of the preconditioned problem the same as the original problem? See Federico's reply.

Comment: I agree with Federico Poloni, unless some conditions are satisfied the solutions will not be the same. If you want the least squares solution to the original system, then this method of preconditioning will not work. But, we should remember that the least squares solution is a compromise. It doesn't solve the linear system, because there are no solutions to the linear system. Among those non-solutions, you are picking the one which has the smallest residual in $l_2$-sense, which would be different in $l_1$ sense. So, is the lsqr solution to the naively preconditioned system useful to you?

Comment: If not, you may want to do a literature review on preconditioning techniques for overdetermined sparse least squares problems. I think Miroslav Tuma has a few papers on that. Alternatively, if this problem coming from an optimal control problem or a PDE constrained optimization problem, then looking into preconditioner for those problems may give a better idea.

Comment: If we use @ChennaK's approach, we should be solving (if I didn't make sign mistakes) $(M^{-1} + M^{-T}A^TA)x = M^{-T}A^{T}b_0 + M^{-1}b_1$. I don't know if it would be effective, though. But this would give you the least squares solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

The naive idea doesn't work immediately. The solutions of
$$
\min \Bigg\|\begin{pmatrix}
A \\
I
\end{pmatrix}
x
-
\begin{pmatrix}
b_0\\b_1
\end{pmatrix}
\Bigg\|$$
and
$$
\min \Bigg\|\begin{pmatrix}
P^{-1}A \\
I
\end{pmatrix}
x
-
\begin{pmatrix}
P^{-1}b_0\\b_1
\end{pmatrix}
\Bigg\|$$
are different, in general (unless $P$ is orthogonal).